# Express.js/CookieSession with Passport working but maxAge isn't

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express, passport.js

I am using Passport-Facebook and CookieSession to auth an user to log into my web application.
Everything works fine, except I am unable to set the session expire time.

```
app.use(cookieSession({
    secret: 'I love stackoverflow',
    cookie: { maxAge: 60000 } // 1 minute : this isn't working.
}));
passport.serializeUser(...);
passport.deserializeUser(...);
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(...));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

I'm using express 4.9.
Anyone know what cause this problem?
If I change cookieSession to session, everything works fine.
However I don't want the cookie store in my server, so I want to use cookieSession.

CookieSession maxAge isn't compatible with Passport?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question.

I solve my problem by using

```
cookie: { maxage: 60000}
```

Note that it's max**a**ge not max**A**ge.

I would recommend the author of cookieSession to use the same name with other packages.
Hope I can help you if you also have the same problem.

Comment: Note: CookieSession has fixed this, if you're using the latest version, you should use max**A**ge